# Grails: <g:each> tag, sort attribute

Tags: grails

There is a way to sort in the  tag in 'desc'? And is it possible to sort by two columns?
I know that there is the possibility to pass the element already sorted in the controller but would be useful to have the chance also in the gsp tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. The `<g:each>` tag does not support sorting and I don't think it should. Any logic (like setting sort order) should not live in the view itself.

Answer (score 7):

Not optimal, but in a pinch you can sort the collection inline:

```
<g:each in="${[2,3,6,1,10].sort{a,b -> a < b ? -1 : 1}}">
${it}
</g:each>
```

In general I agree with mfloryan.  Putting logic in the view is a slippery slope, but there's a time and a place for everything.

Comment: I understand your point but I don't see the problem to have the possibility to sort an array with: .sort{it.something [order:'desc']}, for example

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment.